# How can users buy nodes they can create?

Tags: 7, commerce

I want users to pay 5$ for each node they want to create.

They should be able choose, on registration, to pay from 1 to 400 nodes and more later if needed. The nodes should unpublish after a year with an option for a user to renew. Another option is to have multiple roles for purchase, each with a predefined number of nodes he can create, and let users choose the role on registration.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a Commerce subproject called [Commerce Node Checkout](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_node_checkout) that does node publish purchasing with the option for expiration.

> Integrate with Commerce in order to allow you to charge users to
>   create nodes. It is possible to have multiple different product
>   offerings for each node type, so the user can pick the product they
>   want to purchase when creating the node. An example use-case would be
>   a classifieds site that charges people to post listings.

It's purchase process is on demand, rather than purchasing a credit quota, so you might have to look at something different to base your project on depending on how important the quota functionality is.

An alternative role-based approach would be the [Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license) Roles submodule and something like the [Node Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_limit) module to setup your quota-per-role requirement. You'd also have to find a node expiration solution (e.g. [Node Expire](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_expire)) as well.